# Flash as3 compare from Textinput

Tags: actionscript-3, textinput

hi i have Text input a button .
I want to compare the values from the textInput box with values from a array.
and if the number in the box is true to start playing the video.

Comment: i tried to assign the instance name to a variable and to compare the variable in if statement... i am a beginner in flash programing i know only the basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and compare the values to the box like this:

```
for (var i:int =0 ; i < myArray.length; i++){
   if(textInput.text == myArray[i])
        //Start playing video here
   }
}
```

EDIT:

Now I've seen what you're trying to do (I think), here's what you need to do:

1) Add a listener to the button

2) Inside the handler function, iterate your array and check values

3) If value is same as text, then start the video

```
var myArray:Array = ["1","2","3"]; 

bbt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame); 

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame(event:MouseEvent):void //starting the video 
{ 
    for (var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ 

        if(textInput.text == myArray[i]){ 
            gotoAndPlay(5); 
        }
    }
}
```

If you're only going to have numbers in the array, you can simplify the loop further:

```
for (var i:int =1 ; i < 4; i++){ //Will loop 3 times, with i equalling 1, 2, and 3
    if(textInput.text == i){//Checks text directly against i, rather than array[i]
        gotoAndPlay(5); 
    }
}
```

Comment: var myArray:Array = ["1","2","3"];

for (var i:int =0 ; i < myArray.length; i++){
   if(textInput.text == myArray[i]){

   bbt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame(event:MouseEvent):void //starting the video
{
 gotoAndPlay(5);
}     

 }
}

Comment: In future, provide as much information in the original question as possible - but if you look at my answer, I've modified it to account for what you've shown me. Have a go and tell me how you get on.

Comment: hi again, how can i compare the value from the string not the lenght in the same script i have a couple of values and i need to check them if the input value it's correct to go and play "correct" if it's not to go to and play "fail"